# Any way to print the sum of consecutive similar items in a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to print the sum of consecutive similar items in a list.

Is there a better code to do this? My code missing to give the last result! Any advice?

[**Code**]

```
lst=['+1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '+1', '-1', '+1', '+1']
output=[]
s=int(lst[0])
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    if lst[i]==lst[i-1]:
        s+=int(lst[i])
    else:
        output.append("{0:+}".format(s))
        s=int(lst[i])

print(output)
```

[**Input**]

```
['+1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '+1', '-1', '+1', '+1']
```

[**Expected Output**]

```
['+1', '-3', '+1', '-1', '+2']
```

[**Current incomplete Output**]

```
['+1', '-3', '+1', '-1']
```

Comment: The input is always a list of characters and you want the output to be the same?

Comment: @RobertoT, Yes is it.

Comment: Why not work directly with integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use itertools.groupby

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>>
>>> a = ['+1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '+1', '-1', '+1', '+1']
>>>
>>> result = [sum(map(int, group)) for key, group in groupby(a)]
>>> result
[1, -3, 1, -1, 2]
```

But note that this will return a list of integers, but you can iterate over the result again to format it

```
>>> [f"{'+' if r > 0 else ''}{r}" for r in result]
['+1', '-3', '+1', '-1', '+2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of your current_element also while summing up.
And also the sum needs to be appended to the end after the for loop.

```
lst = ['+1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '+1', '-1', '+1', '+1']
lst = [int(i) for i in lst]

output = []
s = lst[0]
current_element = lst[0]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    if current_element == lst[i]:
        s += lst[i]
    else:
        output.append("{0:+}".format(s))
        s = lst[i]
        current_element = lst[i]
output.append("{0:+}".format(s))
        
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `grupby` from `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst=['+1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '+1', '-1', '+1', '+1']
result = [f"{sum(map(int, l[1])):+}" for l in groupby(lst)]
```

Comment: May be `[f"{sum(map(int, g)):+}" for _, g in groupby(lst)]` would be clearer.